# How to use git bisect on a remote repository?

Tags: git, sha, git-bisect, bisect, remote-repository

I'm creating a Python module that would allow for users to run git bisect on a user specified repository, but I don't quite know how to make git bisect work for a remote repository, one that is not on the machine calling the function. I don't want to use git clone every time because that would be counter intuitive and cost lots of space on the disk. Is there a way to use git bisect on a remote repo?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  `git bisect` requires a working tree or an index because you need to have some way of getting access to the contents of a particular revision to test it.  That necessarily requires that you have a repository on your system.

You could use a partial clone from a recent version of Git to do `git clone --filter=blob:none` to clone only trees and commits and then fetch any necessary blobs on checkout.  This will decrease the clone time, but will require that you be online and have access to the repo during the process in order to fetch the needed blobs.